# Working with Multiple Managed Object Contexts Questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, merge, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I currently do multiple network requests via several threads executing in parallel, thus have a managed object context for each thread, and each thread sets attribute values for Core Data entities. So here is the dilemma, each network request gets small amounts of data at a time, and there are hundreds (or even thousands) of these requests, and I wish to perform saves after all network operations have occurred (so that I can safely assume that saved data means that everything was successfully downloaded and written to store). So two questions:

1. Do I save each managed object context after each thread is done writing to the context, or do I store all managed object contexts in memory, and at the end cycle through all of them and perform saves? (After writing this out, it became obvious that saving on the go would be the more efficient method, but I would still like to hear your thoughts.)
2. Is there any way to merge managed object contexts without performing a save operation? I am currently merging contexts via the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification notification and was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: You going to spawn "thousands" of threads/operations?

Comment: Yeah it sounds stupid, I know, but it wouldn't be all at once, only 2 or 3 threads would actually be running at the same time. The purpose is for pulling data from a web server.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you can "store all managed object contexts in memory, and at the end cycle through all of them and perform saves". Each MOC should be confined to the thread where it's created, therefore I don't see how you can effectively cycle through all MOCs without breaking this confinement rule... But you probably realized that already...

I also believe that merging MOCs via the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification is the most efficient method. I would even argue that it's easiest to save the MOCs after each object insert (e.g. when you import data). That way you minimize the scope of each merge! And since merges are performed in memory, there is little overhead in them being more granular.

Comment: +1 This is the only real solution. You can merge based on the other two notifications but that will be very, very slow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave it more thought and am thinking that explicitly merging the contexts isn't even necessary unless I want the data to be refreshed on other MOC's that are currently in memory, correct? And considering while I am importing the data, I do not need it refreshed immediately, I can merely not merge and when I need to reference the new data I can perform a fetch then. What do you think? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: How you communicate changes between contexts is entirely up to you. Merging changes into say, the main MOC, after each import, has the advantage that you don't have to perform that extra fetch after the import is done. Also, it keeps your main MOC coherent. If you don't care about that though, you can skip the merging. As I said, it's entirely up to you, think of what makes more sense for your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an controller class for all the threads and use only one Managed context to save your data.

After an thread finish download call an delegate in your ThreadControlerClass merge the data with your old data and then save when all the thread finish download. 
If your data is too big you can do some intermediate saves.

Comment: I don't see how this can work. Having the same context operating on multiple threads would cause a trainwreck.

Comment: not on multiple threads but on one thread that will create thread for downloading and after one thread is finish just notify the ThreadControllrClass that you have finished with some data or you have failed.